# iPad opening downloaded document in wrong app

Tags: ms-office, mobile-safari, adobe, ipados

I have downloaded some word documents off safari, but when I try and open them, they open in Adobe Acrobat Reader, rather than Microsoft Word. Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue, and make the documents open in the correct application.

Comment: what are the file names? or at least the extension

Comment: I wonder if removing Acrobat from the iPad, opening a few documents (hopefully in Word) and then re-downloading Acrobat might do the trick...

Comment: @Steve Chambers yes good idea.  I've never seen a docx files displayed by Safari.  Does that happen?

Comment: I suppose word would have the facility to navigate to the file ?

Comment: Depending on the Word document, yes absolutely. Complex ones don't render well but heck Textedit.app on macOS opens most Word files.